# How to download files from net programmatically in Android?

Tags: android, download

In my application downloading loads of files from web they were around 200Mb files(Zipped). How do I download files programmatically in Android? Actually my concern is about performance of code. How do I handle errors and network problem in between?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Here's some code that I recently wrote just for that:

```
    try {
      URL u = new URL("http://your.url/file.zip");
      InputStream is = u.openStream();

      DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(is);

      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int length;

      FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + "file.zip"));
      while ((length = dis.read(buffer))>0) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
      }

    } catch (MalformedURLException mue) {
      Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "malformed url error", mue);
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
      Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "io error", ioe);
    } catch (SecurityException se) {
      Log.e("SYNC getUpdate", "security error", se);
    }
```

This downloads the file and puts it on your sdcard.

You could probably modify this to suit your needs. :)

Comment: I think 1024 (1K) bytes buffer isn't the "best way"? 1500 is better, I also tried 5000 and it was faster.

Comment: I think 4096 is better

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point out that Android 2.3 (API Level 9) introduces a new system service called the [`DownloadManager`](http://d.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html). If you're OK with only supporting 2.3, then you should definitely use it. If not, you can either:

1. Check if the `DownloadManager` is available and use it if it is. If it's not (Android < 2.3), download the file yourself, for example as described by xil3.
2. Don't use `DownloadManager` at all, if you think it's too much work. However, I strongly believe you will benefit from its use.

Comment: DownloadManager is totally undone to developers work with it. You will have more trouble than benefits if you use it to something more than just 1 activity and 1 file to download

Comment: Hi, can DownloadManager handle somethings like download interrupt, resume download, scheduled download, multiple files download? I've tried DownloadManager for a while but I just can download 1 file at a time, and when download is interrupt, I have to download all again. Thanks