# Downloading Mp3 in Android Programmatically from a URL

Tags: java, android

I want to download an Mp3 sound from web server with URL of the sound. I don't know what is the best way to do it! I've also taken a look at these questions. Kindly guide me in right direction.

[Downaload a file programatically on android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1714761/downaload-a-file-programatically-on-android)

[What is best way to download files from net programatically in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896457/what-is-best-way-to-download-files-from-net-programatically-in-android)

Comment: Which of those have you tried? What are your concerns with those samples?

Comment: I've tried the 1st one! I want to know, How can I save the downloaded raw data as mp3 sound to sdcard

Answer (score 0):

Try this code and let me know

```
File output = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
    fileName);
if (output.exists()) {
  output.delete();
}

InputStream stream = null;
FileOutputStream fos = null;
try {

  URL url = new URL(urlPath);
  stream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
  InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
  fos = new FileOutputStream(output.getPath());
  int next = -1;
  while ((next = reader.read()) != -1) {
    fos.write(next);
  }
```